# JTextArea doesn't resize

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, resize, jtextarea

I tried to set `JTextArea` to `JPanel` as

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JTextArea ta=new JTextArea();
ta.setColumns(20);
ta.setEditable(false);
ta.setLineWrap(true);
ta.setRows(5);
ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);

panel.add(ta,BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
panel1.setLayout(new VerticalLayout(5,VerticalLayout.BOTH));
panel1.add(panel);

JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
    ...
```

The thing is... when the `panel1` is re-sized wider and then back narrower the `JTextArea` becomes **cut off**. I mean its rows do not restore to 5 but hold as 1 and so all its text is in one line , of course,  the `WrapStyleWord` is inactive :S

So my question is how to make the `JTextArea` restore to its original scale on frame re-sized?

Here is the [VerticalLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AverticallayoutmanagersimilartojavaawtFlowLayout.htm) code.

...

Well, based on Guillaume Polet snippet, I tried to write some kind of vertical panels *list* but the previously mentioned problem takes place :( Here is the code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTextArea {

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");


        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setLayout(new VerticalLayout(5, VerticalLayout.BOTH));


        JPanel mainPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane();
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        sp.setViewportView(listPanel);

        mainPanel.add(sp);

        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTextArea().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public MyPanel(){

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        ta.setText("Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world " + "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world "
                + "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world " + "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world ");
        ta.setColumns(20);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        ta.setRows(5);
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        this.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        }

    }

    public static class VerticalLayout implements LayoutManager {

        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates centering. Also used to designate center anchoring.
         */
        public final static int CENTER = 0;
        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates right justification.
         */
        public final static int RIGHT = 1;
        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates left justification.
         */
        public final static int LEFT = 2;
        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates stretching the component horizontally.
         */
        public final static int BOTH = 3;

        /**
         * The anchoring constant that designates anchoring to the top of the display area
         */
        public final static int TOP = 1;
        /**
         * The anchoring constant that designates anchoring to the bottom of the display area
         */
        public final static int BOTTOM = 2;
        private int vgap; // the vertical vgap between components...defaults to 5
        private int alignment; // LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER or BOTH...how the components are justified
        private int anchor; // TOP, BOTTOM or CENTER ...where are the components positioned in an overlarge space
        private Hashtable comps;

        // Constructors
        /**
         * Constructs an instance of VerticalLayout with a vertical vgap of 5 pixels, horizontal centering and anchored to the top of the
         * display area.
         */
        public VerticalLayout() {
            this(5, CENTER, TOP);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a VerticalLayout instance with horizontal centering, anchored to the top with the specified vgap
         *
         * @param vgap
         *            An int value indicating the vertical seperation of the components
         */
        public VerticalLayout(int vgap) {
            this(vgap, CENTER, TOP);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a VerticalLayout instance anchored to the top with the specified vgap and horizontal alignment
         *
         * @param vgap
         *            An int value indicating the vertical seperation of the components
         * @param alignment
         *            An int value which is one of <code>RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER, BOTH</code> for the horizontal alignment.
         */
        public VerticalLayout(int vgap, int alignment) {
            this(vgap, alignment, TOP);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a VerticalLayout instance with the specified vgap, horizontal alignment and anchoring
         *
         * @param vgap
         *            An int value indicating the vertical seperation of the components
         * @param alignment
         *            An int value which is one of <code>RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER, BOTH</code> for the horizontal alignment.
         * @param anchor
         *            An int value which is one of <code>TOP, BOTTOM, CENTER</code> indicating where the components are to appear if the
         *            display area exceeds the minimum necessary.
         */
        public VerticalLayout(int vgap, int alignment, int anchor) {
            this.vgap = vgap;
            this.alignment = alignment;
            this.anchor = anchor;
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private Dimension layoutSize(Container parent, boolean minimum) {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
            Dimension d;
            synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
                int n = parent.getComponentCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                    if (c.isVisible()) {
                        d = minimum ? c.getMinimumSize() : c.getPreferredSize();
                        dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, d.width);
                        dim.height += d.height;
                        if (i > 0) {
                            dim.height += vgap;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap + vgap;
            return dim;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Lays out the container.
         */
        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
                int n = parent.getComponentCount();
                Dimension pd = parent.getSize();
                int y = 0;
                // work out the total size
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    y += d.height + vgap;
                }
                y -= vgap; // otherwise there's a vgap too many
                // Work out the anchor paint
                if (anchor == TOP) {
                    y = insets.top;
                } else if (anchor == CENTER) {
                    y = (pd.height - y) / 2;
                } else {
                    y = pd.height - y - insets.bottom;
                }
                // do layout
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    int x = insets.left;
                    int wid = d.width;
                    if (alignment == CENTER) {
                        x = (pd.width - d.width) / 2;
                    } else if (alignment == RIGHT) {
                        x = pd.width - d.width - insets.right;
                    } else if (alignment == BOTH) {
                        wid = pd.width - insets.left - insets.right;
                    }
                    c.setBounds(x, y, wid, d.height);
                    y += d.height + vgap;
                }
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return layoutSize(parent, false);
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return layoutSize(parent, false);
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Not used by this class
         */
        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Not used by this class
         */
        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getName() + "[vgap=" + vgap + " align=" + alignment + " anchor=" + anchor + "]";
        }
    }

}
```

I am not pretty sure how to make JTextArea come to its original width? Or maybe there is some more optimal way?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: `frame.getContantPane().add(panel1);`  That code would not compile.  So it **cannot be the code used to see a run-time problem.**

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, You're right, thanks. I was writing it by hand so mistyped a little :) I fixed it

Comment: 'Fix it' with an SSCCE (that is copy/pasted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are having trouble posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so maybe you can get started from this one, possibly change it, and then edit your question showing us the problem you are having.

EDIT: (Changed SSCCE according to updated question)

The problem is that the ViewPortView of the scrollpane does not implements Scrollable. Try the code below with the dedicated class ScrollablePanel which is added as the ViewPortView.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestTextArea {

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");

        class ScrollablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

            /**
             * Returns the preferred size of the viewport for a view component. This is implemented to do the default behavior of returning
             * the preferred size of the component.
             * 
             * @return the <code>preferredSize</code> of a <code>JViewport</code> whose view is this <code>Scrollable</code>
             */
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }

            /**
             * Components that display logical rows or columns should compute the scroll increment that will completely expose one new row
             * or column, depending on the value of orientation. Ideally, components should handle a partially exposed row or column by
             * returning the distance required to completely expose the item.
             * <p>
             * The default implementation of this is to simply return 10% of the visible area. Subclasses are likely to be able to provide a
             * much more reasonable value.
             * 
             * @param visibleRect
             *            the view area visible within the viewport
             * @param orientation
             *            either <code>SwingConstants.VERTICAL</code> or <code>SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL</code>
             * @param direction
             *            less than zero to scroll up/left, greater than zero for down/right
             * @return the "unit" increment for scrolling in the specified direction
             * @exception IllegalArgumentException
             *                for an invalid orientation
             * @see JScrollBar#setUnitIncrement
             */
            @Override
            public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
                switch (orientation) {
                case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                    return visibleRect.height / 10;
                case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                    return visibleRect.width / 10;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid orientation: " + orientation);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Components that display logical rows or columns should compute the scroll increment that will completely expose one block of
             * rows or columns, depending on the value of orientation.
             * <p>
             * The default implementation of this is to simply return the visible area. Subclasses will likely be able to provide a much
             * more reasonable value.
             * 
             * @param visibleRect
             *            the view area visible within the viewport
             * @param orientation
             *            either <code>SwingConstants.VERTICAL</code> or <code>SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL</code>
             * @param direction
             *            less than zero to scroll up/left, greater than zero for down/right
             * @return the "block" increment for scrolling in the specified direction
             * @exception IllegalArgumentException
             *                for an invalid orientation
             * @see JScrollBar#setBlockIncrement
             */
            @Override
            public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
                switch (orientation) {
                case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
                    return visibleRect.height;
                case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
                    return visibleRect.width;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid orientation: " + orientation);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Returns true if a viewport should always force the width of this <code>Scrollable</code> to match the width of the viewport.
             * For example a normal text view that supported line wrapping would return true here, since it would be undesirable for wrapped
             * lines to disappear beyond the right edge of the viewport. Note that returning true for a <code>Scrollable</code> whose
             * ancestor is a <code>JScrollPane</code> effectively disables horizontal scrolling.
             * <p>
             * Scrolling containers, like <code>JViewport</code>, will use this method each time they are validated.
             * 
             * @return true if a viewport should force the <code>Scrollable</code>s width to match its own
             */
            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }

            /**
             * Returns true if a viewport should always force the height of this <code>Scrollable</code> to match the height of the
             * viewport. For example a columnar text view that flowed text in left to right columns could effectively disable vertical
             * scrolling by returning true here.
             * <p>
             * Scrolling containers, like <code>JViewport</code>, will use this method each time they are validated.
             * 
             * @return true if a viewport should force the Scrollables height to match its own
             */
            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
                return false;
            }

        }

        JPanel listPanel = new ScrollablePanel();
        listPanel.setLayout(new VerticalLayout(5, VerticalLayout.BOTH));

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
        sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        sp.setViewportView(listPanel);

        mainPanel.add(sp);

        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());
        listPanel.add(new MyPanel());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTextArea().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {

            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setText("Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world " + "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world "
                    + "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world " + "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world ");
            ta.setColumns(20);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setRows(5);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);

            this.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }

    }

    public static class VerticalLayout implements LayoutManager {

        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates centering. Also used to designate center anchoring.
         */
        public final static int CENTER = 0;
        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates right justification.
         */
        public final static int RIGHT = 1;
        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates left justification.
         */
        public final static int LEFT = 2;
        /**
         * The horizontal alignment constant that designates stretching the component horizontally.
         */
        public final static int BOTH = 3;

        /**
         * The anchoring constant that designates anchoring to the top of the display area
         */
        public final static int TOP = 1;
        /**
         * The anchoring constant that designates anchoring to the bottom of the display area
         */
        public final static int BOTTOM = 2;
        private int vgap; // the vertical vgap between components...defaults to 5
        private int alignment; // LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER or BOTH...how the components are justified
        private int anchor; // TOP, BOTTOM or CENTER ...where are the components positioned in an overlarge space
        private Hashtable comps;

        // Constructors
        /**
         * Constructs an instance of VerticalLayout with a vertical vgap of 5 pixels, horizontal centering and anchored to the top of the
         * display area.
         */
        public VerticalLayout() {
            this(5, CENTER, TOP);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a VerticalLayout instance with horizontal centering, anchored to the top with the specified vgap
         * 
         * @param vgap
         *            An int value indicating the vertical seperation of the components
         */
        public VerticalLayout(int vgap) {
            this(vgap, CENTER, TOP);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a VerticalLayout instance anchored to the top with the specified vgap and horizontal alignment
         * 
         * @param vgap
         *            An int value indicating the vertical seperation of the components
         * @param alignment
         *            An int value which is one of <code>RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER, BOTH</code> for the horizontal alignment.
         */
        public VerticalLayout(int vgap, int alignment) {
            this(vgap, alignment, TOP);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a VerticalLayout instance with the specified vgap, horizontal alignment and anchoring
         * 
         * @param vgap
         *            An int value indicating the vertical seperation of the components
         * @param alignment
         *            An int value which is one of <code>RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER, BOTH</code> for the horizontal alignment.
         * @param anchor
         *            An int value which is one of <code>TOP, BOTTOM, CENTER</code> indicating where the components are to appear if the
         *            display area exceeds the minimum necessary.
         */
        public VerticalLayout(int vgap, int alignment, int anchor) {
            this.vgap = vgap;
            this.alignment = alignment;
            this.anchor = anchor;
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private Dimension layoutSize(Container parent, boolean minimum) {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
            Dimension d;
            synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
                int n = parent.getComponentCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                    if (c.isVisible()) {
                        d = minimum ? c.getMinimumSize() : c.getPreferredSize();
                        dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, d.width);
                        dim.height += d.height;
                        if (i > 0) {
                            dim.height += vgap;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap + vgap;
            return dim;
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Lays out the container.
         */
        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
                int n = parent.getComponentCount();
                Dimension pd = parent.getSize();
                int y = 0;
                // work out the total size
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    y += d.height + vgap;
                }
                y -= vgap; // otherwise there's a vgap too many
                // Work out the anchor paint
                if (anchor == TOP) {
                    y = insets.top;
                } else if (anchor == CENTER) {
                    y = (pd.height - y) / 2;
                } else {
                    y = pd.height - y - insets.bottom;
                }
                // do layout
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                    int x = insets.left;
                    int wid = d.width;
                    if (alignment == CENTER) {
                        x = (pd.width - d.width) / 2;
                    } else if (alignment == RIGHT) {
                        x = pd.width - d.width - insets.right;
                    } else if (alignment == BOTH) {
                        wid = pd.width - insets.left - insets.right;
                    }
                    c.setBounds(x, y, wid, d.height);
                    y += d.height + vgap;
                }
            }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return layoutSize(parent, false);
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return layoutSize(parent, false);
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Not used by this class
         */
        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Not used by this class
         */
        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getName() + "[vgap=" + vgap + " align=" + alignment + " anchor=" + anchor + "]";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for the edit (I know it is not the first time you fix this in my code). I keep on forgetting the default close operation on the frame (I run all my code from IDE), although I am fully aware of it. I'll try to watch that.

Comment: OK, thank you for your snippet. Based on it I tried to figure out some kind of SSCCE :) I edited my question. Please watch it

Comment: @user592704 I updated my SSCCE as well ;-) and I think you should find this much more acceptable. The problem comes from the fact that the ViewPort view did not implement Scrollable. Let us know

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any reason why not use `JScrollPane`, `LineWrap` and `WordWrap` works correctly in the `JScrollPane`, then for `JPanel` will be better to use another `LayoutManager`

- put `JTextArea` to the `JScrollPane`
- `JPanel` required (I'm quite to ignore used `VerticalLayout`) to change default `LayoutManager` (`FlowLayout`) to the `BorderLayout`
- put `JScrollPane(myTextArea)` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`

Comment: I am not using JScrollPane because I am interested in non-scrollable and non-editable JTextArea. Just to set text in it with wordwrap support

Comment: ... but the thing is the JTextArea doesn't become the original one if it is once resized :S Is there a way to walk it around but keep the VerticalLayout manager? Or could you advise some alt vertical flow layout manager?

Comment: then you have to add [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) and with override `componentResized()`, sure in the case that you want to avoid flickering during resize you have to invoke code from Swing Timer, if resizing continue call Timer#restart

Comment: `way to walk it around but keep the VerticalLayout manager?` sorry I don't know something about this LayoutManager, nor used ..

Comment: "sorry I don't know something about this LayoutManager, nor used" No, I mean could you advise some kind of another vertical flow layout manager? A layout which supports vertical filled components adding...

Comment: `BoxLayout` pretty accepting `PrefferedSize` came from childs, and `SpringLayout` or `GrigBagLayout` for most complex GUI (MigLayout), for simple GUI to use `BorderLayout`